# android WorkRequest is running in an infinte loop

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My task that I want to run is in doWork(). This part of the application begins when `scheduleUpdateJob()` is called. It in turn executes `doWork()` through a work request which does the operation. At the end of `doWork()`, `updateSchedule()` is called which sets a periodicRequest to execute `doWork()` every 15 minutes. My problem is that updateSchedule is immediately calling doWork which calls its calling funtion in an infinite loop. Am i doing something wrong.

```
public class EarthquakeUpdateWorker extends Worker {

    private static String PERIODIC_WORK_ID = "PERIODIC_WORK_ID";

    public EarthquakeUpdateWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    public static void scheduleUpdateJob(Context context) {
        WorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class).setConstraints(Constraints.NONE).build();
        WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
        workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
  
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        // STUFF_TO_DO
        updateSchedule(getApplicationContext());
        return Result.success();
    }

    private static void updateSchedule(Context context) {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED).build();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Boolean autoUpdate = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PreferenceActivity.PREF_AUTO_UPDATE, true);
        int updateFreq = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(PreferenceActivity.PREF_UPDATE_FREQ, "60"));

        if(autoUpdate) {
            PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class, updateFreq, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
            WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
            workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
           
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the need for the separation between scheduleUpdateJob and updateSchedule? Why not just make updateSchedule public and call it within your application startup logic? Then you can remove the call from within doWork. Further, look into [enqueueUniquePeriodicWork](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)). It will allow you to call updateSchedule several times without worrying about multiple copies of the WorkRequest being enqueued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `updateSchedule()` from your `doWork()` callback.  Just schedule it as a periodic work request from the start, instead of a one-time that is then rescheduled as a periodic after it runs once.

This is the whole point of periodic work requests:  they are repeated again later, automatically, until explicitly canceled.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I have instead used `enqueueUniquePeriodicRequest()` with the `REPLACE` policy. The reason i have `updateSchedule()` call every time the work runs is to see if the preferences have changed or user has disabled autoUpdate. As of now I see no other soloution.

Answer (score 1):

Set **[initial delay](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#delayed_work)** while creating the `PeriodicWorkRequest`

**Replace**:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class, updateFreq, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

**With**:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(EarthquakeUpdateWorker.class, updateFreq, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setInitialDelay(updateFreq, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

Comment: The best practice is to use PeriodicWorkRequest only and remove the dependency of OneTimeWorkRequest (i.e. scheduleUpdateJob)